# Multiple customers/email addresses for one subscription in stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I feel like this should be possible and even common but haven't come across it in the documentation or on SO yet.

I sell a B2B subscription, and the norm in the industry is to send an invoice to the business to be paid by the accounting department. In many cases, the company is paying for access to the platform for multiple employees.

I'd like to pass an array of customers for a single subscription, so that when the subscription expires, all users lose access (or renew) in the following year. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not supported. Stripe is an abstraction for payments that you'll need to model appropriately for your business. In this case, your "Customer" could be the company, with the accounting representative as the billing contact. Then in your system you'd map individual user accounts to that customer/company account to grant or deny access to the service or features.

You do not need to (and should not) create a Stripe Customer for each individual employee at the company accessing your service if that does not fit the payments model for your business.

Comment: that's a good answer - although I've just come up with a problem where i need to send several billing emails under one Stripe.Customer (let's say to three departments just for their info) - seems like it's impossible - anyone has a solution?